# Why android/java choose sunday first weekdays for chinese language

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I use following code to get locale sensitive `firstDayOfWeek` index, but when using Chinese lang, Sunday is still first. Same as English language. The code is adopted from jetpack compose `DatePicker`, and `DatePicker` also uses Sunday first for Chinese language.

```kotlin
class WeekdayName(val locale:Locale) {

    fun dayInISO8601(day: Int): Int {
        val shiftedDay = (day + 6) % 7
        return if (shiftedDay == 0) return /* Sunday */ 7 else shiftedDay
    }

    val firstDayOfWeek: Int =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            WeekFields.of(locale).firstDayOfWeek.value
        } else {
            dayInISO8601(Calendar.getInstance(locale).firstDayOfWeek)
        }
}
```

It's strange for Chinese users. As https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week says

> Most of Europe and China consider Monday the first day of the week

Is my code to get `firstDayOfWeek` right? Or is this intended?

Edit: simple app code to reproduce https://github.com/tkkcc/WhyAndroidUseSundayFirstForChinese

Comment: What is the value of `locale`? I do not know about Kotlin, but since you asked for Java - it is returning MONDAY: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylvOL.png (Java 21 and 22)

Comment: Well, the first thing to note is you don't have a fully reproducible example. Like, I don't see the packages for the classes you're using, but I can make some assumptions. Please resubmit a working example of the problem.

This question also has nothing to do with JeyPack, Kotlin or Android. Data/time/calendar are all core to the java packages. 

Since you're using `Calendar`, you need to see how it interprets first day of the week, and you may have to choose a different calendar - the default, I believe, is the `Gregorian` calendar, which makes sense for the Christian, western world

Comment: for the record, here's [the gregorian calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar)

Comment: just tested with Java 17 - that is returning SUNDAY - seems like it was changed between 17 and 21 (that is, probably it was not intended to be Sunday)

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno repo added for reproduce

Comment: [This source](http://chartsbin.com/view/41671) lists Sunday as first day for China, Hong Kong, and Macao. [This one](https://savvytime.com/current-week/china) too.

Comment: Java 12 [reports Sunday](https://ideone.com/wadtFY) for `Locale.CHINA`.